How to prevent desktop Firefox from loading apple-touch-icon?
I found that desktop Firefox (version 124 at the time of writing) always downloads apple-touch-icon when the web page contains:
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=180x180 href=/apple-touch-icon.png>

There is also a relevant known bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1745680
How can I work around this bug for a static page?
